# Scala capture all implicits of the calling scope?

Tags: scala, implicit, implicit-parameters

Suppose I have a scope `A` in which some implicit values are defined, and a code block `c` that uses those implicit values. I also have scope `B` which has implicits of compatible type, so that if I copy the code block `c` into `B`, it would compile and run without problem. This is ugly, of course, since I'm duplicating `c` in two places, so I would like to move `c` into its own function. Now, the function signature of `c` has to look like:

```
def c(args...)(implicit implicitArgs...) = ...
```

where `implicitArgs` are the implicit values used in `c`. Given that some frameworks (Scalding, in my case) defines many implicits, the signature here can quickly get out-of-hand. Is there any syntax to say "carry all implicit values in the calling scope"? Or is there a clever way around this?

cheers,
Geoff

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work, but you can give it a try. You could group implicits into container objects.

Example: Let's say you have implicits of type `X`, `Y` and `Z`, and you don't always want to add three `implicit` arguments to every method. Say you define a container object for those:

```
class MyImplicits(val x:X, val y:Y, val z:Z)
```

In order to allow for automatic creation of the `MyImplicits` wrapper, you create an object method that derives it from the individual implicits. Likewise, you define implicit un-wrapper methods:

```
object MyImplicits {
  implicit def wrap(implicit x:X, y:Y, z:Z):MyImplicits = new MyImplicits(x, y, z)
  implicit def unwrapX(implicit wrapper:MyImplicits):X = wrapper.x
  implicit def unwrapY(implicit wrapper:MyImplicits):Y = wrapper.y
  implicit def unwrapZ(implicit wrapper:MyImplicits):Z = wrapper.z
}
```

Let's say we have a method like this:

```
def foo(...)(implicit implicits:MyImplicits) = ...
```

The following should work:

```
implicit val implicitXIsInScope:X = ...
implicit val implicitXIsInScope:Y = ...
implicit val implicitXIsInScope:Z = ...
foo(...) // MyImplicits should automatically be created
```

Likewise, if an instance of `MyImplicits` is in implicit scope, you should be able to call any method that requires an implicit instance of `X` without needing to unwrap it explicitly.

I did not try this out though. Please let me know if it works!

Comment: Yeah, something like this would work, although it's still quite a hoop to jump through. I suppose I wanted a mechanism or syntax for dynamically scoped implicit values.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to "curry implicit args":

```
def myfunc(arg:Something)(implicit session:Otherthing):Unit = ....

val curriedFunc = myfunc(value)(_:Otherthing)

curriedFunc(valueOfOtherThing)
```

For more information see **Partials without Currying** at http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/function-currying-in-scala

**Note**: I'm new to Scala and I don't know all best-practices.